# Mapping an array to object parts

Tags: javascript

I have an object as,

```
const a = {
   "val1": 1,
   "val2": 2
}
```

And I want to map through it as,

```
const entries = Object.entries(a);

const mappedA = entries.map(entry => {type: entry[0], value: entry[1]})
```

How can I achieve this? This keeps throwing an error

Comment: `{}` after the `=>` create a *code block*, not an object

Comment: The question is not clear on the expected output.